# WCF service with 2 or more parameters

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, parameters, svc

I have to create a WCF service that executes a query (no problem at the moment). My problem is that this query needs two parameters that the user types into a web form and submits with a button. How can I pass those 2 parameters from the web form to the service? I have only created services that receive only one parameter, not more than one
This is my only problem, I'm be able to read the JSON result and organize it in the form

Thaks a lot

Comment: You must add a new method to your WCF Service which takes the right number of arguments.

Comment: Yes. the question is how to transfer the parameters to the service through a link. For example, if I sent a parameter, the link would be something like https://myservice.com/getpeople/1234567, where the parameter I sent is 1234567. How do I pass two parameters through the link? Will I have to use forward slash in each parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [UriTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/uritemplate-and-uritemplatetable), 
`UriTemplate` is a class that encapsulates a URI template. The constructor takes a string parameter that defines the template.
like :

```
[ServiceContract]  
interface ICustomer  
{  
  //"View It" -> HTTP GET  
    [WebGet( UriTemplate="customers/{id}" )]  
  Customer GetCustomer( string id ):  
  
  //"Do It" -> HTTP PUT  
  [WebInvoke( UriTemplate="customers/{id}", Method="PUT" )]  
  Customer UpdateCustomer( string id, Customer newCustomer );  
}
```

Useful links:

[URI Processing with UriTemplate and UriTemplateTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model-overview#uri-processing-with-uritemplate-and-uritemplatetable)

[How to pass multiple parameters on WCF Restful service using C# in ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/142968/How-to-pass-multiple-parameters-on-WCF-Restful-service-using-C-in-ASPNet/)